# Sharepoint 2010 port changes on login page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication

I have a sharepoit site with local address  http://sharepoint:5887. I make alternative access for public site with address http://test.mysite.ru. this site has a forms authentication.
If in public site (http://test.mysite.ru) I press login button then login page starts opening by  http://test.mysite.ru:5887 (public address + port from local address)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behaviour. You cannot change the port from 5887 to 80 through AAM. It just changes the Url and not the server port on which the IIS listens.

If you want to translate the port from 5887 to 80 , you need to place a proxy server such as ISA server.

Answer (score 0):

Read this

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814%28office.12%29.aspx

Search for

Alternate Access Mapping in Sharepoint